# url rewriter in iis and '&' character

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

in `web.config` i have added a rule for rewriting , all works until adding & character in `sendto` section

```
    <RewriterRule>
        <LookFor>.*-p(.\d+)-news</LookFor>
       <SendTo>~/default.aspx?articleid=$1</SendTo>
    </RewriterRule>
```

it works , but when i add more GET paramatere in  `<SendTo>` rewriting not work at all.

```
    <RewriterRule>
        <LookFor>.*-p(.\d+)-news</LookFor>
       <SendTo>~/default.aspx?articleid=$1&tabid=112312</SendTo>
    </RewriterRule>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is solution that if found Here : [IIS Forum](https://forums.iis.net/post/2053790.aspx)

`&` is special character and use `&amp;` instead.